# How to know the ping in ms

Tags: java, android

I know how to check if a certain site/IP ADDRESS is reachable or not. But I wonder if it's possible to know the response time or the ping in millisecond (ms) for a specific site or an IP address?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ping value in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077669/ping-value-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

It is very much possible :)
Just make sure you have the right permissions(You put this in your AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

My code that works absolutely well.

```
public String ping(String url) {
        String str = "";
        try {
            java.lang.Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "ping -c 1 " + url);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                           process.getInputStream()));
            int i;
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            String op[] = new String[64];
            String delay[] = new String[8];
            while ((i = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
                output.append(buffer, 0, i);
            reader.close();
            op = output.toString().split("\n");
            delay = op[1].split("time=");

            // body.append(output.toString()+"\n");
            str = delay[1];
            Log.i("Pinger", "Ping: " + delay[1]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // body.append("Error\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }
```

The code above is as simple as you can get.
To call the code...

```
String str = ping("www.google.com");
//Unecessary but it makes it easier
android.widget.Toast.makeText(this, str, android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have ICMP out of the box. There are three things you can do:

1. Rely on CLI and use that to get the response from the ping command [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077669/ping-value-in-java).
2. Use sockets to calculate latency between sending and receiving information [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599797/tcp-round-trip-time-calculation-using-java).
3. Use an ICMP library.